# Binomial riddle

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, multiarmed-bandit, iteration-methods

I have a riddle that i cannot solve:
I'm a recruiter searching for the best basketball player in a town. There are 100 candidates in the town. 99 of them have a probability of basket the ball of 0.501, 0.502, 0.503,...,0.597, 0.598, 599 respectively. 1 of the 100 candidates has a probability of basktet the ball of 0.7.
The goal is, by only counting the throws and successes, find the one player of 0.7 probability with a 99% of confidence with less than 14000 total throws (sum of all players throws).
Can you solve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?